# Automatically click button

Tags: magento, button

I want to customize an button on magento to click it automatically every 30 minutes, this is the button http://prntscr.com/fmrxa9

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried? We are here to help not write codes for you.

Comment: can you put your code what you have tried, that will give more clarity to answer you

Comment: I just installed one extension have not created any code,